# Azure pipeline - 'The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace'

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, github, github-actions

I know this question has countless asking already. However, I didn't find any working solution for me.

I have a .NET website project and I am using Entity Framework 6.
Locally, the project has no problem, everything is running just fine. But when I push it to my master branch on GitHub so that it will be deployed to my Azure website, the message shows up:
[image]

Here's my yml file:

```
    on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '3.1.301'

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: nuget restore MyOnlineCV.sln

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

It's happening on the step 'Build with dotnet'. How am I supposed to solve it?
Thank you by advance

And my .csproj for the curious ones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A9A08EBE-F204-4570-9B5F-1EBE5D3E63AA}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Data</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Data</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Category.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Diploma.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Experience.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.Context.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.Context.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Skill.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <EntityDeploy Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx">
      <Generator>EntityModelCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>MyOnlineCVDataModel.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EntityDeploy>
    <None Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx.diagram">
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="DbScripts\drop_create.txt" />
    <Content Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.Context.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>MyOnlineCVDataModel.Context.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="MyOnlineCVDataModel.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <DependentUpon>MyOnlineCVDataModel.edmx</DependentUpon>
      <LastGenOutput>MyOnlineCVDataModel.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{508349B6-6B84-4DF5-91F0-309BEEBAD82D}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework">
      <Version>6.4.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework.fr">
      <Version>6.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

The build already worked sometimes but after one push it just stopped working. I haven't changed any back-end file tho. I'm lost

### Edit

Here's the project packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.fr" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you show `packages.config` for your project/solution?

Comment: I added the file

Comment: @Dyanek Did you see the packages restored during `Restore NuGet packages` step?  Have you tried delete the `packages.config` file and recreate it? It seems you are using GitHub Actions, not Azure Pipeline for the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to solve the problem, I did this:
I uninstalled every Entity Framework nuget.
I removed packages.config and in the .csproj I removed this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework">
       <Version>6.4.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework.fr">
      <Version>6.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I reinstalled Entity Framework, here's the new packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

And the added lines in the .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" />
...
<None Include="packages.config" />
...
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project is referencing to missing NuGet packages on this computer. Use the NuGet packages restoration option to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is: {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" />
```

Then I committed to git and the pipeline worked correctly.

Note that the step `run: nuget restore MyOnlineCV.sln` in the pipeline is essential. Without it an error appears.

Answer (score 1):

You are building your project here with the 4.7.2 framework, but in the yml you are referencing the .Net Core Framework. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. In fact, my solution's main project is using .Net Core Framework. The secondary project with EF6 is using 4.7.2 framework